# Open Microsoft Store from windows phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing an app with Phongap. I have 3 buttons with links to the app in each store (Google Play, Itunes and Microsoft Store). I would like to open links to the app in each store depending on the phone you are using (this is already solved). I can do it for Itunes and Android but I can't find the way to open the link using installed Microsoft Store. I am doing this:

- **Android:** market://details?...
- **ITunes:** itms-apps://itunes.com/...
- **Microsoft Store:** ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. But this is the one I needed:

ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=

More details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-store-app